# Redmine doesn't display mercurial repository

Tags: mercurial, repository, redmine

I connect repository in projects settings: set repository type as mercurial and set root directory as "/repositories/hg_test" and when i click Repository tab in project i get **"The entry or revision was not found in the repository"**

Repository separately works great, i can push and pull.

I try to drop tables "changes" and "changesets" in redmine database and do

```
ruby script/runner "Repository.fetch_changesets" -e production
```

I get some records in this tables again. Records from my 'hg_test' repository. I think this mean that redmine SEE that repository but cant DISPLAY it.

Why he cant, how to solve this problem? Maybe i must configure something in redmine.

PS OS - Ubuntu 10.04, webserver - nginx with passenger

Answer (score 1):

If your repositories' directory is mounted via SSHFS, be sure to enable `-o allow_other` when mounting.

Answer (score 0):

Redmine must have permissions to access to your repository. Add webserver's user (in my case it was www-data) in the group ownership of files and directories of repository.

Comment: I made the repository 777 and still no luck.

Answer (score 0):

this solution worked for me:

edit (copy *.yml.example if not created yet) file /opt/redmine/config/configuration.yml, and change this line with your hg executable path:

```
scm_mercurial_command: /usr/bin/hg
```

restart the webserver containing redmine (typically redmine itself or apache)

test